# How to show drop-down for only clicked element in `ngFor` in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, dropdownbox, ngfor

I have a list of items displayed in a table using `ngFor`, each of these items has a corresponding drop-down box which is only showed when you click on the item. The problem is, I only want to show the dropdown box that was clicked and hide the rest item's dropdown box that was opened previously. Currently, I am able to open drop-down box of an item for multiple items. However, I only want to show the dropdown for the clicked item. For example:

[image]

However What I want is that when I click on different items, I want all the dropdown to hide and only show the current clicked one.

Is this possible to do in angular2?

I have a directive that looks for click event and toggles them, which is only used to show/hide, but i don't know how to fix my current issue:

Here is my code:

```js
// assume necessary imports {..}...
@Directive({
  selector: '[rbDropdown]'
})
export class NgDropdownDirective {
  constructor(private _ref: ElementRef) {}

  @HostBinding('class.open') get opened() {
    return this.isOpen;
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event', '$event.target']) open() {
    console.log(this._ref.nativeElement);
    //this._ref.nativeElement.children[1].classList.add('table-dropdown-open');
    if (this._ref.nativeElement.children[1].classList.contains('table-dropdown-open')) {
      this._ref.nativeElement.children[1].classList.remove('table-dropdown-open');
      this.isOpen = false;
    } else {
      this.isOpen = true;
      this._ref.nativeElement.children[1].classList.add('table-dropdown-open');
    }
  }
  private isOpen = false;
}
```

Here is my `ngFor` for the items that I have:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let module of modules">
    <td class="text-center">
      <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div><span class="title-Code">{{module.Code}}</span></div>
      <div class="small text-muted"><span>{{module.Name}}</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>{{ module.Credit}}</td>
    <td>{{ module.Structure }}</td>
    <td>{{ module.Tags }}</td>
    <td>{{ module.LastEdit }}</td>
    <td rbDropdown>
      <a class="test" #thisTag></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu table-dropdown" role="menu">
        <li>
          <a (click)="_showDialogue =! _showDialogue; _getModuleCode(module)"><img src="../../assets/img/pencil.svg" alt="" width="13px">Edit Module</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a (click)="removeModule(module.Code)"><img src="../../assets/img/delete.svg" alt="" width="13px">Remove Module</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Im sorry I don't know how to use plunker to show my issue.

Your help would be highly appreciated for this wonderful community!

Comment: Generalizing your problem - you have few dropboxes and you want to hide every of them expect the clicked one?

Comment: I have a dropdown box for each row, but they are hidden initially, and only visible when you click on them. But currently I can show dropdown box for multiple items, and they remain open if I click on another item, but answer to your question? Yes @Kinduser

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I used the below template

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of data">
     {{id}} &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
     <button (click)="showItems($event)"> {{item.class}} </button>
     <students style="visibility:hidden" [studentsList]="item.studentsList"> </students>
</div>
```

The students component will look as below

```
<div *ngFor="let item of studentsList">
          {{item.id}} &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
               <button> {{item.name}} </button>
</div>
```

Method

```
showItems(val){

    val.srcElement.nextElementSibling.style['visibility']="visible";

}
```

This method will toggle the corresponding element, **if the hierarchy is followed as such**.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/aCsNhTyMDQQJvIEKSQb3?p=preview)**